# How to Generate Color Array as material-color-generator when give the HEX Color code

Tags: angular-material, angular6

I need to generate color array from given the basic HEX color code.

**Ex** -: *my Base Color code is #e91e63,

so then generate color array like this http://mcg.mbitson.com/#!?mcgpalette0=%23e91e63

also i try this [NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-palette-generator) for that. bcz i can't understand how to config with my angular project

**please help me**

```
$mdThemingProvider.definePalette('mcgpalette0', {
  '50': 'fce4ec',
  '100': 'f8bcd0',
  '200': 'f48fb1',
  '300': 'f06292',
  '400': 'ec407a',
  '500': 'e91e63',
  '600': 'e61a5b',
  '700': 'e31651',
  '800': 'df1247',
  '900': 'd90a35',
  'A100': 'ffffff',
  'A200': 'ffd0d8',
  'A400': 'ff9dae',
  'A700': 'ff8498',
  'contrastDefaultColor': 'light',
  'contrastDarkColors': [
    '50',
    '100',
    '200',
    '300',
    'A100',
    'A200',
    'A400',
    'A700'
  ],
  'contrastLightColors': [
    '400',
    '500',
    '600',
    '700',
    '800',
    '900'
  ]
});
```

Comment: Hello Pavithra, please take note that you're using syntax from AngularJS, the former framework for Angular. The website you linked is meant for AngularJS Material. Check out all of the themes here: https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/a9e877675b71ad4afe6e23fb1e9b376bf7dc0661/src/lib/core/theming/_palette.scss#L39-L670

Comment: Hello Edric, already i used angular 6. i need to generate color array from given base hex color code.so please tell me how to generate pragmatically color array in angular 6